# searching for some example for make a page dynamic or adjustable on front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

i was having a problem in searching for some example for make a page dynamic or adjustable on front end can any one help me in this please 
for eg on front end a client wants to adjust the links from one place to another or can chage backgrounds looks like fonts + background color + placement of divs etc can any one help me in doing so or can anyone help me with example on internet which solves my problem i will be thankfull to you.......

little code

```
<body style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="div1">
<div id="div1.1">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
    <div id="div1.2">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div id="1.3">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div id="1.4">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

here i am handling a major div div1 and child divs div1.1,div1.2,div1.3,div1.4 and i want to change place of these child divs

Comment: what's the problem? go to css file and change their positions..

Comment: i want to do it on front end and then save changes

Comment: what i am searching is for a client side

Comment: a client could perform these functions if we wish to

Comment: check jquery's ressizable property

Comment: thanku abdul jabbar it found to be helpfull

Comment: and is there any way to edit all pages at front end by admin on front end only

Comment: Well it is not impossible but if your website is already designed and now you want to add that functionality to it.. im afraid that'll be too much of a work depending on what sort of editing admin want.. if its little like adding few textboxes on button click and stuff like that, then it shouldn't be that big of a problem.. but you will have to write all that code on back end first!

Comment: can you let me know of any such example

Comment: and like we get a page name localhost/home.aspx and can it be converted into localhost/home in that place what is this known as ?

Comment: check these https://www.cushycms.com/en  http://all-free-download.com/free-vector/editable-website-templates.html  http://www.evolutionindesignz.com/editable_websites.html#

Comment: and it's localhost/home.aspx because it's an asp page hosted on your local server running on machine.. when you host it on internet then you can choose whatever name you want.. .aspx will come because it's the page's extension which the browser is opening

Comment: yes sir how do we do on live websites

Comment: learn web development or hire some professionals to do it for you

Comment: kkkk thnku  how do i vote you up when you have not given any code i would like to do that

Comment: I've added an answer from this chat.. you can mark that